# Help needed in counting ways.

Tags: combinatorics, sudoku

In the 3rd section titled : 'Counting Solutions' for the webpage [here](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/Mahmood/Count.html), there is calculation as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsv1S.png) that has exercise based on filling the $9$ sub-cubes of Sudoku named as $B_1, B_2, B_3$ in the first row, & so on as shown in diagram below.
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  B_1&B_2&B_3\\
  -&-&-\\
  B_4&B_5&B_6\\
  -&-&-\\
  B_7&B_8&B_9\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

> *Exercise:-* List all the possible ways of filling in the first rows in B2 and B3, up to reordering of the digits in each block. 
>   $$ \left[
> \begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc}
>   1&2&3&*&*&*&*&*&*\\
>   4&5&6&*&*&*&*&*&*\\
>   7&8&9&*&*&*&*&*&*\\
>   -&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-\\
>   *&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*\\
>   *&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*\\
>   *&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*\\
> -&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-\\
>   *&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*\\
>   *&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*\\
>   *&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*\\
> \end{array}
> \right] $$

It states as hint: There are ten ways of doing this so that swapping B2 and B3 in these ten ways give you ten more ways, for a total of twenty.

I am unable to get figure of $10$ ways & request help. 
Let, $B_2$ be the first to be filled. So, selects $3$ elements out of $6$ left. Say, the first row of $B_2$ has selected $3$ elements: $4,5,6$. This leads to $^6P_3(=120)$ ways for the selected $3$ elements of the first row of $B_2 $.
These $3$ elements then need be reordered to get $^3P_3(=3!=6)$ further ways. 
 Applying the product rule, get $720$ ways.

  For the first row of $B_2$ get further $3!$ arrangements. The multiplication leads to $720*3= 2160$ ways.

Even if I ignore the ways of selecting $3$ elements from $6$, still get $3!*3!= 36$ ways.

---

An unrelated but quite imp. question on shidoku, on [mse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/413682/424260) here. It helps to find impossible cases for a $4\times 4$ block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says "[up to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to) reordering of the digits in each block".

So, for example, we consider
$$1\ 2\ 3\mid 4\ 5\ 6\mid 7\ 8\ 9$$
is the same as
$$1\ 2\ 3\mid 5\ 6\ 4\mid 7\ 8\ 9$$

So, the total number is given by $\binom{6}{3}=20$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am unable to get an approach to directly get $10$ for the sub-cube $B_2$ or $B_3$. The only way to get is to divide $\binom{6}{3}=20$ by $2$.

Comment: @jiten: I'm not very sure what the hint is saying, but one way is as follows : we consider first the number of the possible ways such that $4$ is in $B_2$. The number is $\binom{5}{2}=10$. So, the total number is $10\times 2$.

Comment: So, choosing (combinations) of $3$ elements from $6$ is the same as taking one element as fixed for $B_2$ & then getting the no. of choices (of filling $2$ elements from $5$ available); & multiplying this by $2$ (for which ever cube gets filled first) for getting the total number of choices available.

Comment: I hope that the page#$1$ at : http://www.afjarvis.staff.shef.ac.uk/sudoku/sudoku.pdf shows the set of $10$ values for each $B_2, B_3$; & their swap leading to a total of $20$ choices.